# Inverse of matrix with varying parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, inverse

Ok so I need some sort of verification on this. I have run into this matrix $\begin{pmatrix} e^t&3e^{-t}\\e^t&e^{-t} \end{pmatrix}$ and I need to find the inverse of this matrix. The book simply ignores the fact that there is a function in the matrix and computes the inverse normally (without the functions). However when we start throwing in $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ we start to see complicated inverses. **What exactly is the procedure to determine the inverse of these types of matrices and how do you know if it is "safe" to take the inverse of the fundamental matrix?** These matrices come up in differential equations for solutions to non-homogenous systems. How would you take the inverse had it been $\begin{pmatrix} \sin t& 3\cos t \\ \sin t& \cos t\end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: There exist some $t$ where the matrix is singular.

Comment: Are we just setting $ t $ to be some parameter say 0?

Comment: $t$ is a variable that the matrix depends on, i.e., $A(t)$. And to find the inverse of a matrix $A(t)$, we must guarantee that the determinant of $A(t)$ (which is some function $f$ that depends on $t$) must be not zero. i.e., $\mathrm{det}\,A(t)=f(t)\neq0$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Do you know that

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac1{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d&-c\\-b&a\end{pmatrix},\qquad \text{if}\;\; ad-bc\ne0$$

Answer (score 1):

To make a long story short, everything you learned before this point with numbers instead of functions is more or less the same. In this case, we use that fact that a matrix can be inverted if it has none zero determinate. So the standard inversion matrix formula holds.

$det = ad - bc = e^t e^{-t} - 3e^t e^{-t} = e^{0} - 3 e^{0} = -2 \neq 0 \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: So are we just setting $ t $ to be zero for these 2 cases

Comment: No, we're taking them as functions! We just can't make sense of the inverse if $\exists t$ such that the determinate is zero.

Comment: How come they just found the inverse of the matrix without $ e^{t} $ and $ e^{-t} you can't just factor it out

Comment: You can check if a matrix is invertible around a point if you plug in a value, but that doesn't justify global inversion.

Comment: ahhhh I see! I was trying to do the row-echelon form method but in the end I need to do row-echelon form because what if the matrix was $3 \times 3$

Comment: If it was a 3 by 3, exact same story. We need none zero determinate! There are a handful of methods of actually computing the inverse if you know it's invertible though.

Comment: I see but the row-echelon form is a bit more complicated than this right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14069/discussion-between-jeb-and-adam)